# Wireless connection problem

Tags: wireless, hardware

I need help in setting up wireless connection in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Not detecting any drivers, in spite of having a modem and a router.

Comment: Go to 'Dash Home' located in top left corner of your desktop and search for 'additional drivers'. Install these drivers and let us know what happens.

Comment: @Jay that won't work for ubuntu>12.04 also the machine needs to be connected to internet. @OP, please include result of `lspci`, `lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all` in your question (you can edit your question). Enter those above commends in terminal and post the result here.

Comment: I went on 'Dash Home' and tried to serch on additional drivers. But it said an internal error has occured, please remove any third party pakage and try again. Can you help reg this please?

Comment: @user151572 - please answer Web-E question otherwise there is very little that we can help you with.